# Need help executing a .bat file using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a .bat file (m.bat) using a simple php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo exec('m.bat');
echo "Done!";
} else {
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

this just displays the content of the .bat file in the browser, and if I drop the 'echo' before 'exec' it does nothing at all. :(

Comment: What happens if you try `exec('m.bat', $out); print_r($out);`?

Comment: I get Array ( [0] => [1] => (batch file contents..) ) Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec()` executes commands, but doesn't open files.

You need to read the content of m.bat in order to execute it.

Try this

```
$file = file_get_contents("m.bat");
$output = exec($file);
print_r($output);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe that's because `exec()` returns an array. I have edited my answer. Please try `print_r`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `.bat` files run on Windows. If your server isn't Windows, it won't run and will instead just return the contents of the file.

If you are on Windows, try the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

```
echo `m.bat`;
```

Note those are backticks, not single quote marks. This is functionally equivalent to [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: No luck with the print_r will try backticks

Comment: I think you also need the `cmd` from Mario's answer, so I'm giving that my +1

Comment: the backticks just echo the contents of the batch file :( its a windows machine running Win Sever 2008 R2

Comment: Can you run your batch script directly? The bug might be in the batch

Answer (score 1):

Windows batch files don't execute themselves IIRC. You should run them through one of the two interpreters:

```
print shell_exec("cmd m.bat");
```

(Otherwise that's the same as using the backtick operator.)

Comment: You need to check the `error.log` then. It will contain any output from `stderr` (which wasn't redirected here). Also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For other users reading this - what helped for me:

The user running your Webserver need access to file. Maybe if you use Apache and the built-in system account for the service, it won't have permission to access to your .bat file. I've changed the user for the service to the local system administrator for testing and it works fine. This was the error.

Don't forget to check your webserver's error log!